# XML generation using Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I am trying to create an XML from oracle which has parent child relationship between them.

The data of table is shown below. Here one employee can be linked to one or more manager.
 
Here **empID 101** is linked to **3 Manager 100,102,104**

```
Employee_ID  Manager_ID
101           100
105           100
101           102
101           104
```

The Final XML should be like this.

```
<view_hierarchy chm="com.hierarchy">
<link>
    <parentID ID="100">
        <contains>
            <child ID="101"/>
            <containby>
                <parentID ID="102"/>
                <parentID ID="104"/>
            </containby>                    
        </contains>
        <contains>
            <child ID="105"/>             
        </contains>
    </parentID>
</link>
</view_hierarchy>
```

Please find below the SQL which I am using but it is not giving correct "containby" details.

```
SELECT XMLElement (
 "view_hierarchy",
                   XMLATTRIBUTES('com.hierarchy.mdm'as "chm"), 
                   XMLElement ("link", XMLAgg(
                   XMLElement("parentID", 
                   XMLAttributes(manager_id as "GTIN"),  
                  XMLElement ("contains",XMLAgg
                                (   
                  XMLELEMENT (
                  "child", 
                            XMLAttributes(employee_id as "GTIN"),   
                            XMLElement ("containby"    , XMLElement("parentID", XMLAttributes
(manager_id as "GTIN" )   )     
                                      ) 
                            )                                    
                                         )              
                  ) 
                                  )))
                )   ||''
  FROM employees where manager_id=100 group by manager_id
```

Comment: I think, your data is wrong, employee 101 has 3 managers.

Comment: It can have multiple Managers. And the same has to be reflect in containby part, in which it will show all the manager except the one under which it is listed

Comment: So, who is the primary manager or is it random?

Comment: Primary manager is 100

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you want:

```
with employees as(
select 101 Employee_ID , 100 Manager_ID from dual
union all
select 105 Employee_ID , 100 Manager_ID from dual
union all
select 101  Employee_ID , 102 Manager_ID from dual
union all
select 101 Employee_ID , 104 Manager_ID from dual
)
SELECT XMLElement (
 "view_hierarchy",
                   XMLATTRIBUTES('com.hierarchy.mdm'as "chm"), 
                   XMLElement ("link", XMLAgg(
                   XMLElement("parentID", 
                   XMLAttributes(e1.manager_id as "GTIN"),  
                  XMLElement ("contains",XMLAgg
                                (   
                  XMLELEMENT (
                  "child", 
                            XMLAttributes(e1.employee_id as "GTIN"), e2.x                                 
                                         ))           
                  ) 
                                  )))
                )   ||''
  FROM employees e1
left join (select    
                            XMLElement ("containby"    , XMLAgg(XMLElement("parentID", XMLAttributes
            (e2.manager_id as "GTIN" )   )     
                                      ) )
                             x, employee_id   from employees e2
                             where e2.manager_id !=100
                            group by e2.employee_id) e2 on e2.employee_id=e1.employee_id 
where e1.manager_id=100 
group by e1.manager_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
      SELECT XMLELEMENT (
        "view_hierarchy",
        XMLATTRIBUTES ('com.hierarchy.mdm' AS "chm"),
        XMLELEMENT (
           "link",
           XMLELEMENT (
              "PARENT_ID",
              XMLAttributes (manager_id AS "GTIN"),
              XMLELEMENT (
                 "contains",
                 XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT (
                           "child",
                           XMLAttributes (emp.employee_id AS "GTIN"),
                           XMLELEMENT (
                              "contained_by",
                              (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT (
                                                "parent_id",
                                                xmlattributes (
                                                   emp_p.manager_id AS "GTIN")))
                                 FROM employees emp_p
                                WHERE emp_p.manager_id <> emp.manager_id
                                      AND emp.employee_id =
                                            emp_p.employee_id))))))))
     || ' '
FROM employees emp
WHERE emp.manager_id = 100
GROUP BY emp.manager_id
```

Comment: I strongly disadvice from using a subselect in the `select`-part of a statement. That can ruin your performance.

Comment: One subselect was unnecessary and i removed, for my opinion that xml is not in good structure but to achieve that xml this query is the simple and more easy to understand i think.