# hierarchy records

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data

I am trying to create an XML from Oracle which has parent-child relationship between them.

The data of table is shown below. One `child_ID` can be linked to one or more `parent_ID`.
Here, `101` is linked to 2 IDs `100` and `200`.

```
child_ID  Parent_ID
--------  ---------
100       1000
101       100
102       100
101       200
1010      101
1011      101
1020      102
1021      102
```

The XML should be in the following format if the input value for `parent_id` is `100`.

```
<view_hierarchy chm="com.hierarchy">
<link>
    <ID refno="100">
        <contained_by>
            <ID refno="1000"/>
        </contained_by>
        <contains>
            <ID refno="101">
                <contained_by>
                    <ID refno="200"/>
                </contained_by>
                <contains>
                    <ID refno="1010">
                    </ID>
                    <ID refno="1011">
                    </ID>
                </contains>
            </ID>
            <ID refno="102">
                <contains>
                    <ID refno="1020">
                    </ID>
                    <ID refno="1021">
                    </ID>
                </contains>
            </ID>
        </contains>
    </ID>
</link>
</view_hierarchy>
```

Here `contained_by` refers to all parents linked to an element, `contains` refers to all children related to the element.

The input `parent_id` value can differ and accordingly the `contains` and `contained_by` needs to be calculated for XML generation.

Comment: Honestly, I expected this question to show up. :-) A nice exercise this will be, if I manage to get to solving it.

Comment: Do you expect cycles in your parent/child relationships? I.e., for example, can a parent `1021` have a child `1000`?

Comment: No. There will never be cyclic relationship

Comment: link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb13gen.htm with example Example 16-31 will help you

Comment: Is it just me, or is that the same as this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376654/xml-generation-using-oracle/27380398#27380398

Comment: @user2179887, it's not. The one you're referencing asked for a level 1 hierarchy. This one asks for a full hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** In the following, the `t_hierarchy` is your source table (since you did not name it in your question).

Although maybe possible to do this via hierarchical SQL, I believe that pure SQL would be a *PITA* to implement and that a regular recursive PLSQL function will do just fine.

First, create yourself a simple **schema-level** collection type

```
create or replace type arr_integers as table of integer;
```

then a function

```
create or replace
function f_parent_child_xml
    ( i_parent_id                   in t_hierarchy.parent_id%type
    , i_visited_nodes               in arr_integers default null )
    return xmltype
is
    l_result                        xmltype;

    l_contained_by_xml              xmltype;
    l_contained_by#                 integer;
    l_contains_xml                  xmltype;
    l_contains#                     integer;

    l_new_visited_nodes             arr_integers;
begin
    if i_visited_nodes is null then
        select
            xmlelement("view_hierarchy",
                xmlattributes('com.hierarchy' as "chm"),
                xmlelement("link",
                    f_parent_child_xml(i_parent_id, arr_integers())
            ))
        into l_result
        from dual;
    else
        select parent_id
        bulk collect into l_new_visited_nodes
        from t_hierarchy
        where i_parent_id in (child_id, parent_id)
        union
        select child_id
        from t_hierarchy
        where i_parent_id in (child_id, parent_id)
        union
        select column_value
        from table(i_visited_nodes);

        select
            xmlagg(
                f_parent_child_xml(H1.parent_id, l_new_visited_nodes)
            ) as xml$,
            count(1) as rows#
        into l_contained_by_xml, l_contained_by#
        from t_hierarchy H1
        where H1.child_id = i_parent_id
            and not exists (
                select 1
                from table(i_visited_nodes) X
                where X.column_value = H1.parent_id
            )
        ;

        select
            xmlagg(
                f_parent_child_xml(H2.child_id, l_new_visited_nodes)
            ) as xml$,
            count(1) as rows#
        into l_contains_xml, l_contains#
        from t_hierarchy H2
        where H2.parent_id = i_parent_id
            and not exists (
                select 1
                from table(i_visited_nodes) X
                where X.column_value = H2.child_id
            );

        select
            xmlelement("ID",
                xmlattributes(i_parent_id as "refno"),
                case when l_contained_by# > 0 then xmlelement("contained_by", l_contained_by_xml) end,
                case when l_contains# > 0 then xmlelement("contains", l_contains_xml) end
            )
        into l_result
        from dual;
    end if;

    return l_result;
end;
```

---

Running e.g.

```
select f_parent_child_xml(101)
from dual;
```

or

```
select f_parent_child_xml(101).getStringVal()
from dual;
```

yields (after manual reformatting):

```
<view_hierarchy chm="com.hierarchy">
    <link>
        <ID refno="101">
            <contained_by>
                <ID refno="100">
                    <contained_by>
                        <ID refno="1000"></ID>
                    </contained_by>
                    <contains>
                        <ID refno="102">
                            <contains>
                                <ID refno="1021"></ID>
                                <ID refno="1020"></ID>
                            </contains>
                        </ID>
                    </contains>
                </ID>
                <ID refno="200"></ID>
            </contained_by>
            <contains>
                <ID refno="1011"></ID>
                <ID refno="1010"></ID>
            </contains>
        </ID>
    </link>
</view_hierarchy>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: @user3852047, don't forget to show appreciation by accepting and/or upvoting my answer. That's how it goes here, on stackoverflow.com - that's how we get rewarded for spending our time helping others. :-)

Comment: It doesn't work as expected when I pass parent ID as 101, since i don't get the hierarchy for 100 which comes in <contained_by> details.

Comment: @user3852047, you did not state that you expect a full hierarchy in the `contained_by` nodes, too, and your example also did not imply such an option.

Comment: My Bad :( The contained_by clause which has 100 should have all hierarchy except that of  101 itself.

Comment: @user3852047, I was thinking about forcing you to posting new question (so as to gain another 25 rep ;-)), but then I changed my mind. :-) Answer updated with the fully recursive nesting in `contained_by` nodes as well. Have fun!

Comment: I have tried the second option but still when I pass ID as 101, I don't get the hierarchy for 100, which lies in the contained_by element.     I have already posted a new question for the same. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418457/xml-generation-for-hierarchy-with-any-inputs

Comment: contained by loop is not working when we pass child id to the input

Comment: @user3852047: *"I have tried the second option but still when I pass ID as 101, I don't get the hierarchy for 100"* ... I **did** get the hierarchy, I can update it in the answer. *"contained by loop is not working when we pass child id"* ... You never said anything about passing child id to the function, only parent ids. :-) You're overcomplicating it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The output while I am executing select f_parent_child_xml(101).getStringVal()
from dual; is different than what you have pasted. whatever the output you have mentioned is the one I am looking for.

Comment: @user3852047: *"The output while I am executing select f_parent_child_xml(101).getStringVal() from dual;"* ... Then you must have done something wrong. I'm updating the answer to contain only the full-recursive function, redeploy it once again and try it again.

Comment: I think it is working now.. Let me do some more checks..BTW.. thanks a ton.. appreciate your patience